# Command line server for the IE WebDriver has stopped working while running selenium webdriver automation in c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver

I read few post regarding issue -Command line server for the IE WebDriver has stopped working but did not find any resolution yet. 
I Tried below ways:
1. Resetting IE Setting.
2. Remove unwanted toolbars, addons from IE.
3. Resetting All Zones

Some one has also mentioned to check using IEDRiver of 32 bit but i did not find that. Could you please tell me if we have solution for this.

I am facing this issue on :
Windows 7 64 bit + IE 9, IE 10 IE 11

Please see attached snapshot
[image]

Comment: Hi simond, have you tried with IEDriver(32 bit)? In Question you clearly mentioned that you did not find it.  Just want to confirm again the same.

Comment: No i did not find that driver -I am using IEDriver but i dont know whethers its 32 bit or 64 bit ...can you please give me link to down load that too

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Also try with the latest Selenium jar file i.e selenium-java-2.47.1

Comment: Hey ..I am using C# ....i have mentioned it in title ...can we use Java Driver for c#...??

Comment: yes C# selenium libraries are different then this, You can download it for 32 bit and add to your project path.

Comment: From where to download c# selenium 32 bit ..?? link provided does not show any 32 bit etc ..there is only selenium 2.47.0.0 for c# and i am already using it